# How to display base64 pdf in angular template file

Tags: angular, pdf, base64, octetstring

I have a base 64 encoded string, I want to display it on my angular template file.

Comment: You want to render `base64` string as image, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to do

Comment: do you have sample data?

Comment: Also, the `base64` string, is it image (jpg, png) or pdf file?

Comment: To render image you can set the src property of the "img" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img [src]="yourEncodedStringVariable"/>
```

where yourEncodedStringVariable= data:image/png;base64,[your base 64 string]